# How can I echo version number in jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My pipeline script is

```
VersionNumber([
    versionNumberString : '1.0.${BUILD_DAY}', 
    projectStartDate : '1990-07-01', 
    PrefixVariable : ''
    ])
```

Through jobs its creating an enviorment varibale . But through pipeline how can I echo version number string?

Answer (score 1):

just assign it to a environment variable and use it:

```
environment {
  VERSION = VersionNumber([
    versionNumberString : '${BUILD_YEAR}.${BUILD_MONTH}.${BUILD_ID}',
    projectStartDate : '2014-05-19'
  ]);
}
```

then you can output it to a file:

```
steps {
  sh 'echo "$VERSION" > version.txt';  
}
```

or to console:

```
steps {
  sh 'echo "$VERSION"';  
}
```

where ever you use $VERSION it will be replaced with your version number

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code snippet:

```
environment {
        VERSION = VersionNumber([projectStartDate: '2017-05-12', skipFailedBuilds: true, versionNumberString: '${YEARS_SINCE_PROJECT_START, XX}.${BUILD_MONTH, XX}.${BUILDS_THIS_MONTH}', versionPrefix: 'v']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Jenkins **Declarative Pipeline** example:

```
pipeline {

    environment {
        XCODE_BUILD_NUMBER = VersionNumber(projectStartDate: '1970-01-01', versionNumberString: '${BUILD_DATE_FORMATTED, "yyyyMMddHHmm"}', versionPrefix: '')
    }

    stages { 
        stage('Example Print') {
            steps{
                echo XCODE_BUILD_NUMBER
                sh 'add dollar sign when using sh: $XCODE_BUILD_NUMBER' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```